# Dynamically Changing Features of an Overridden TreeView Class

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview, overriding

I am overriding a `TreeView` so that I can highlight the nodes using better colors. As part of the applications options I want to enable the user to change the `TreeView`'s font and the font color when both selected and deselected. The code is below:

```
class MyTreeView : TreeView
{
    // Create a Font object for the node tags and HotTracking.
    private Font hotFont;
    private Font tagFont = new Font("Helvetica", Convert.ToSingle(8.0), FontStyle.Bold);

    #region Accessors.
    public Font hotTrackFont
    {
        get { return this.hotFont; }
        set { this.hotFont = value; }
    }

    //public string unFocusedColor
    //{
    //   get { return this.strDeselectedColor; }
    //   set { this.strDeselectedColor = value; }
    //}

    //public string focusedColor
    //{
    //   get { return this.strSelectedColor; }
    //   set { this.strSelectedColor = value; }
    //}
    #endregion

    public MyTreeView()
    {
        this.HotTracking = true;
        this.DrawMode = TreeViewDrawMode.OwnerDrawText;
        hotFont = new Font(this.Font.FontFamily, this.Font.Size, FontStyle.Underline);
    }

    // Override the drawMode of TreeView.
    protected override void OnDrawNode(DrawTreeNodeEventArgs e)
    {
        TreeNodeStates treeState = e.State;
        Font treeFont = e.Node.NodeFont ?? e.Node.TreeView.Font;

        // Colors.
        Color foreColor = e.Node.ForeColor;

        // Like with the hotFont I want to be able to change these dynamically...
        string strDeselectedColor = @"#6B6E77", strSelectedColor = @"#94C7FC";
        Color selectedColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml(strSelectedColor);
        Color deselectedColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml(strDeselectedColor);

        // New brush.
        SolidBrush selectedTreeBrush = new SolidBrush(selectedColor);
        SolidBrush deselectedTreeBrush = new SolidBrush(deselectedColor);

        // Set default font color.
        if (foreColor == Color.Empty)
            foreColor = e.Node.TreeView.ForeColor;

        // Draw bounding box and fill.
        if (e.Node == e.Node.TreeView.SelectedNode)
        {
            // Use appropriate brush depending on if the tree has focus.
            if (this.Focused)
            {
                foreColor = SystemColors.HighlightText;
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(selectedTreeBrush, e.Bounds);
                ControlPaint.DrawFocusRectangle(e.Graphics, e.Bounds, foreColor, SystemColors.Highlight);
                TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, e.Node.Text, treeFont, e.Bounds,
                                             foreColor, TextFormatFlags.GlyphOverhangPadding);
            }
            else
            {
                foreColor = SystemColors.HighlightText;
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(deselectedTreeBrush, e.Bounds);
                ControlPaint.DrawFocusRectangle(e.Graphics, e.Bounds, foreColor, SystemColors.Highlight);
                TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, e.Node.Text, treeFont, e.Bounds,
                                             foreColor, TextFormatFlags.GlyphOverhangPadding);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if ((e.State & TreeNodeStates.Hot) == TreeNodeStates.Hot)
            {
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(SystemBrushes.Window, e.Bounds);
                TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, e.Node.Text, hotFont, e.Bounds,
                                             System.Drawing.Color.Black, TextFormatFlags.GlyphOverhangPadding);
            }
            else
            {
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(SystemBrushes.Window, e.Bounds);
                TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, e.Node.Text, treeFont, e.Bounds,
                                             foreColor, TextFormatFlags.GlyphOverhangPadding);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see I am currently changing the `Font` `hotFont` using an accessor to the class which seems to work. However, when I try to edit the colors of the focused/unfocused node, VS2010 crashes! What is it that is causing this behaviour exactly and how can I achieve what I want?

Comment: Is focusedColor and unFocusedColor suppose to be a string?  Is the commented out properties where VS crashes?

Comment: Yes you have it correct. Sorry for delayed response...

Comment: I can't replicate the error.  I added the strDeselectedColor and strSelectedColor variables under tagFont declaration with the defaults you were using in DrawItem, uncommented your properties and commented out the variable declaration in the DrawItem event, and everything worked fine.  What is actual error message you are getting?

Comment: A fatal error in VS2010 causing it to stop working giving 'VS2010 has stopped working an needs to close!' error message. It maybe due to the way I invoke the class. I create multiple `TreeView`s in different forms simultaniously. Having said that, this I think is a design time failure. This is an odd error and to stop it from happening I just comment out the above code!? Thanks for your time with this - if you answer the question with the above I will accept it; this is not closed but I am not going to spend any more time on this one as it maybe very esoteric and related to *my* setup only.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ytx0z24%28VS.80%29.aspx

Comment: Cheers Hans, I had never heard of this and had no idea this could be done. All the best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The posted code does not recreate the error when I enabled those commented out properties and added the variables to the control's scope.

A couple of notes though:

Instead of string properties, I would use an actual color:

```
private Color _UnfocusedColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml(@"#94C7FC");
private Color _FocusedColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml(@"#6B6E77");

public Color UnfocusedColor
{
   get { return _UnfocusedColor; }
   set { _UnfocusedColor = value; }
}

public Color FocusedColor
{
  get { return _FocusedColor; }
  set { _FocusedColor = value; }
}
```

Also, make sure to dispose of your drawing objects, such as the SolidBrush objects, or wrap them up in a `Using(...){}` block.